# Computing gradients for outputs taken from intermediate layers and updating weights using optimizer

Tags: computer-vision, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras, gradienttape

I am trying to implement below architecture and not sure in applying gradient tape properly.

[image: LFFD research paper]

In the above architecture we can see, outputs taken from multiple layers in the blue boxes. Each blue box is termed as loss branch in the [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1904.10633.pdf) which contains two losses namely cross entropy and l2 loss. I wrote architecture in tensorflow 2 and using gradient tape for custom training purpose. One thing I am not sure is how should I update the losses using gradient tape.

I have two queries,

1. How am I supposed to use gradient tape for multiple losses in this scenario. I am interested in seeing code!
2. For instance, consider the 3rd blue box(3rd loss branch) in the above image, where we will take inputs from **conv 13** layer and get two outputs, one for classification and other for regression.
   So after computing the losses how I am supposed to update the weights, should I update all the layers above(from conv 1 to conv 13) or should I only update the layers weights which fetched me **conv 13** (conv 11, 12 and 13).

I am also attaching a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63700886/using-gradient-tape-for-custom-training-where-outputs-will-be-taken-from-interme) where I posted a question yesterday in detail.

Below is the snippet which I have tried for gradient descent. Please correct me if I am wrong.

```
        images = batch.data[0]
        images = (images - 127.5) / 127.5

        targets = batch.label

        with tensorflow.GradientTape() as tape:
            outputs = self.net(images)
            loss = self.loss_criterion(outputs, targets)
        
        self.scheduler(i, self.optimizer)
        grads = tape.gradient(loss, self.net.trainable_variables)
        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, self.net.trainable_variables))
```

Below is the code for custom loss function which is used as loss_criterion above.

```
    losses = []
    for i in range(self.num_output_scales):
        pred_score = outputs[i * 2]
        pred_bbox = outputs[i * 2 + 1]
        gt_mask = targets[i * 2]
        gt_label = targets[i * 2 + 1]

        pred_score_softmax = tensorflow.nn.softmax(pred_score, axis=1)
        loss_mask = tensorflow.ones(pred_score_softmax.shape, tensorflow.float32)

        if self.hnm_ratio > 0:
            pos_flag = (gt_label[:, 0, :, :] > 0.5)
            pos_num = tensorflow.math.reduce_sum(tensorflow.cast(pos_flag, dtype=tensorflow.float32)) 
        if pos_num > 0:
            neg_flag = (gt_label[:, 1, :, :] > 0.5)
            neg_num = tensorflow.math.reduce_sum(tensorflow.cast(neg_flag, dtype=tensorflow.float32))
            neg_num_selected = min(int(self.hnm_ratio * pos_num), int(neg_num))
            neg_prob = tensorflow.where(neg_flag, pred_score_softmax[:, 1, :, :], \
            tensorflow.zeros_like(pred_score_softmax[:, 1, :, :]))
            neg_prob_sort = tensorflow.sort(tensorflow.reshape(neg_prob, shape=(1, -1)), direction='ASCENDING')
            prob_threshold = neg_prob_sort[0][int(neg_num_selected)]
            neg_grad_flag = (neg_prob <= prob_threshold)
            loss_mask = tensorflow.concat([tensorflow.expand_dims(pos_flag, axis=1), 
                tensorflow.expand_dims(neg_grad_flag, axis=1)], axis=1)
        else:
            neg_choice_ratio = 0.1
            neg_num_selected = int(tensorflow.cast(tensorflow.size(pred_score_softmax[:, 1, :, :]), dtype=tensorflow.float32) * 0.1)
            neg_prob = pred_score_softmax[:, 1, :, :]
            neg_prob_sort = tensorflow.sort(tensorflow.reshape(neg_prob, shape=(1, -1)), direction='ASCENDING')
            prob_threshold = neg_prob_sort[0][int(neg_num_selected)]
            neg_grad_flag = (neg_prob <= prob_threshold)                
            loss_mask = tensorflow.concat([tensorflow.expand_dims(pos_flag, axis=1), 
                tensorflow.expand_dims(neg_grad_flag, axis=1)], axis=1)

        pred_score_softmax_masked = tensorflow.where(loss_mask, pred_score_softmax, 
            tensorflow.zeros_like(pred_score_softmax, dtype=tensorflow.float32))
        pred_score_log = tensorflow.math.log(pred_score_softmax_masked)
        score_cross_entropy = - tensorflow.where(loss_mask, gt_label[:, :2, :, :], 
            tensorflow.zeros_like(gt_label[:, :2, :, :], dtype=tensorflow.float32)) * pred_score_log
        loss_score = tensorflow.math.reduce_sum(score_cross_entropy) / 
        tensorflow.cast(tensorflow.size(score_cross_entropy), tensorflow.float32)

        mask_bbox = gt_mask[:, 2:6, :, :]
        predict_bbox = pred_bbox * mask_bbox
        label_bbox = gt_label[:, 2:6, :, :] * mask_bbox
        # l2 loss of boxes
        # loss_bbox = tensorflow.math.reduce_sum(tensorflow.nn.l2_loss((label_bbox - predict_bbox)) ** 2) / 2
        loss_bbox = mse(label_bbox, predict_bbox) / tensorflow.math.reduce_sum(mask_bbox)

        # Adding only losses relevant to a branch and sending them for back prop
        losses.append(loss_score + loss_bbox)
        # losses.append(loss_bbox)
    
        # Adding all losses and sending to back prop Approach 1
        # loss_cls += loss_score
        # loss_reg += loss_bbox
        # loss_branch.append(loss_score)
        # loss_branch.append(loss_bbox)
        # loss = loss_cls + loss_reg

    return losses
```

I am not getting any error but my losses aren't minimizing. Here is the [log](https://github.com/Manideep08/LFD_tf/blob/master/config_lic_plt_320_240_3L_2020-08-30-19-54-21.log) for my training.

Someone please help me in fixing this.